# Programmatically add methods to a class with type safety in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a client for a web service, and one of the endpoints takes a single parameter from a possible 20 parameters (which could grow).

I expose a method for each of these possibilities on the client. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```ts
// keys.ts
export const FUNCTION_ONE = 'FunctionOne';
export const FUNCTION_TWO = 'FunctionTwo';
...
export const FUNCTION_TWENTY = 'FunctionTwenty';

// client.ts
import * as keys from './keys';
import { camelcase } from 'lodash';

export default class Client {
    makeCall(method: string): Promise<void> {
        // some implementation
    }
}

Object.values(keys).forEach((key) => {
    (Client.prototype as any)[camelcase(key)] = function () {
        return this.makeCall(key);
    };
});
```

Typescript knows nothing about the methods because they were added programmatically. I don't want to manually write each of these methods because the service might add more and I want it to be easy to just add them to the keys.ts file.

I was thinking of making a modification to the keys which would require me to type out the camelcase form of the key (an acceptable tradeoff) which I could then use to build a type which I could combine with the class. Something like this:

```ts
// keys.ts
function key<T extends string>(command: string, name: T) {
    return { command, name };
}

export const FUNCTION_ONE = key('FunctionOne', 'functionOne');
...

// client.ts
export default class Client {
    // same as before
}

interface ClientInterface<T extends Record<string, { name: string }>> {
    // implementation??
}

export default type Client = ClientInterface<keys>;
```

How can I write this `ClientInterface` type which generates an interface with all the names from the keys as methods? Or is there a better way to do this entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
type ClientInterface<T extends Record<string, { name: string }>> =
    {[N in T[keyof T]["name"]]: () => Promise<void> };
export type ClientType = ClientInterface<typeof keys>;
```

Or if you're willing to actually name your constants in camel case, then it becomes a little simpler, and the "rename" command on the constants will be able to update all calls:

```
type ClientInterface<T> =
    {[N in keyof T]: () => Promise<void> };
export type ClientType = ClientInterface<typeof keys>;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this in practice. The ClientType correctly has all the methods on it, but I can't get interface merging to work because I guess types can't merge with classes. Is there a good way to say that my client is Client & ClientType?

Comment: Got it to work by using `export interface Client extends ClientInterface<typeof keys> {}`